# How does $n^c \lg n, 0<c<1$ compare to other common time complexities

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation

Between what two common time complexities would you place $n^c lg n, 0<c<1$?

The following table illustrates the common time complexities.
Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities)
[image: Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities]

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/755

Answer (score 2):

$O(n^c \log n)$ is above $O(n^c)$ but below $O(n^{c+\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. This is true for any $c \geq 0$, including $c < 1$.

For example, $n^{0.5} \log n$ is not in $O(n^{0.5})$ but is in $O(n^{0.500001})$.

This is one of the reasons for the invention of the "soft O" notation $\tilde{O}(n^c)$, defined as the union of $O(n^c (\log n)^d)$ for all $d \geq 0$. Soft O allows you to fudge log factors and focus on the most important part, which is the highest-order polynomial exponent.